I can't seem to get my UI text showing in game view. It is in scene view though. (Unity)
No matter what I do, the only place my UI will show is in scene view (i.e. not game view)
I have looked for 30 minutes so if anyone can respond please do so.
I tried creating a FontMeshPro. It would show up in the Assets section as a FontMeshPro but I still can't put it into the UI. I don't know if there is another thing I have to do but please let me know.

please read [ask] and [mcve]
